# Actionable events in Calendar event

Tags: outlook, office365, office365connectors

Does anyone know whether it's possible to add Actionable Messages to an calendar event in outlook? I only find examples of Actionable Messages send via email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Actionable Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/) are only supported in Emails and Office 365 Connectors used by Groups, Teams and Yammer.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.